# Tensorflow code accuracy not increasing

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm new to Tensorflow and building a perceptron with 2 hidden layers.
My dataset has 8000 training examples and the code is given below:-

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv("Churn_Modelling.csv")

X=data.iloc[:,3:13].values
Y=data.iloc[:,13].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
le1=LabelEncoder()
X[:,1]=le1.fit_transform(X[:,1])
le2=LabelEncoder()
X[:,2]=le2.fit_transform(X[:,2])
ohe1=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[1])
X=ohe1.fit_transform(X).toarray()

X=X[:,1:]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()
X_train=sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=sc.transform(X_test)

y_train=np.array([[y_train[i]] for i in range(8000)])
y_test=np.array([[y_test[i]] for i in range(2000)])

import tensorflow as tf

hidden1=6
hidden2=6

batch_size=10

x=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,11],dtype=tf.float32)
y=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,1],dtype=tf.float32)

def neural_network(data):
    l1={"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([11,hidden1])),
       "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden1]))}
    l2={"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden1,hidden2])),
        "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden2]))}

    output={"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden2,1])),
            "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))}

    hl1=tf.add(tf.matmul(data,l1["weights"]),l1["biases"])
    hl1=tf.nn.relu(hl1)

    hl2=tf.add(tf.matmul(hl1,l2["weights"]),l2["biases"])
    hl2=tf.nn.relu(hl2)

    output1=tf.add(tf.matmul(hl2,output["weights"]),output["biases"])

    return output1
tcost=[]
def train_neural_network(data):
    prediction=neural_network(data)
    cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y))
    #cost=-tf.reduce_mean(y*tf.log(prediction)+(1-y)*tf.log(1-prediction))
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        epochs=100

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            avg_cost=0

            for i in range(batch_size):
                start=i
                end=start+batch_size
                a=X_train[start:end,:]
                b=y_train[start:end,:]
                _,c=sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict={x:a,y:b})
                avg_cost+=c

                i=i+batch_size
            print("Cost",avg_cost)  
            correct= tf.equal(tf.round(prediction), y)    
#            correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
            accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,"float"))
##           my_acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(y, prediction), tf.float32))
##            print(sess.run(my_acc, feed_dict={x:X_test,y:y_test}))
            print("Accuracy",accuracy.eval({x:X_train,y:y_train}))        
            tcost.append(avg_cost)
        plt.scatter(range(100),tcost,color="blue")
        plt.show()            



train_neural_network(x)
```

No matter what i do the accuracy of my network is not going above 10% on the training set.
I have tried tinkering with learning rate as well as the number of layers and hidden units with no avail even though the cost function is decreasing gradually with each epoch.

Heres what i got at the end:-

Cost 0.0032630344212520868
Accuracy 0.015

Am i implementing the accuracy function wrong?What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` this function only is useful for training because of the optimizations with sigmoid and the cross entropy, for predictions you need to use the `sigmoid` function in your outputs. You are mixing the `logits` with the `predictions`, those are different things.

```
def neural_network(data):
    l1={"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([11,hidden1])),
       "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden1]))}
    l2={"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden1,hidden2])),
        "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden2]))}

    output={"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden2,1])),
            "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))}

    hl1=tf.add(tf.matmul(data,l1["weights"]),l1["biases"])
    hl1=tf.nn.relu(hl1)

    hl2=tf.add(tf.matmul(hl1,l2["weights"]),l2["biases"])
    hl2=tf.nn.relu(hl2)

    logits=tf.add(tf.matmul(hl2,output["weights"]),output["biases"])
    predictions = tf.sigmoid(logits)

    return logtis, predictions

...
logits,prediction=neural_network(data)
cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=y))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked.You really cleared my doubts.